# C# RenderTargetBitmap with grey borders

Tags: c#, wpf, rendertargetbitmap

```
public RenderTargetBitmap GetSketchContentForExport()
    {
        Rect rectBounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(drawingCanvas);

        RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)rectBounds.Width, (int)rectBounds.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

        using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            VisualBrush visualBrush = new VisualBrush(drawingCanvas);
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(), rectBounds.Size));
        }
        renderTarget.Render(drawingVisual);


        return renderTarget;
    }
```

When rendering the canvas content into a bitmap, all the content is displayed but has also grey borders (exactly the parts that are not in the current view).
Editing the resulting image in an external tool (XnView) and using the option "True Colour" fixes that problem. Does anyone see how I can fix this problem in my code? I appreciate any help!

Comment: Does it make a difference if you first draw into the DrawingVisual and afterwards get the bitmap size from `drawingVisual.ContentBounds`?

Comment: drawingContext.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, new Pen(...), new Rect(new Point(), rectBounds.Size));

try drawing the Pen as well

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for your answer, but no, that does not make a difference. The gray borders sill appear.

Comment: @eranotzap That did not work, but thank you for your reply.

Comment: I remember having problems with rendering to bitmap and the solution  was to enclose the rendered control in another container but the details are a bit murky now...